# Camel suspension strategy

Tags: apache-camel

I am using a Camel route (R) to copy files from A to B. But this is event based i.e. there is route R1 which polls a directory (C) and when any file found, its processor triggers R to copy files then suspend R.

I would like to ensure, that while suspending all the existing files in A are copied to B, then only I will suspend. But any shutdown strategy (don't know if this is honored while suspension also) ensures only the on-fly message to be process i.e. only current file (on which R is working on currently) will be copied to B before R is suspended. But I want **all present** files must be copied to B.

How can I ensure that.

Constraints:

1. Route R must be event based, when only an event comes then only it will copy existing log file from A to B, then it will go to sleep untill next event comes
2. If R is made event based and since A is a log folder where all the logs reside, I can not copy all the logs every-time...a huge size
3. I can not delete files from A after copying

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Why do you need R1? Could you not do with a single route R that monitors C for a "ready-file" and only then copies everything from A to B? I assume the "wait for ready file" is why you want to suspend R?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it is easier to use the good old Java stack we used in the "pre-Camel" era. That said, do the file copy on your own in a separate `Processor` (or a Camel unware bean):

```
@Override
public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    final File source = new File("/path/to/in-directory");
    final File desc = new File("/path/to/out-directory");
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);
}
```

For the file copy, the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` from the Apache Commons project is used.

**EDIT:**

As @Petter correctly noted, with this solution, there is no need to create and start a separate route that has to be shutdown again. The directory copy processor could just be added to the `R1` processor where the copying is triggered.

Comment: Good idea. Right tool for the job. However, not sure what value the camel stuff adds here. The copyDirectory call is probably enough. :)

Comment: @Petter You're absolutely right, in this case there is no need to create a separate route. The file copy processor could just be embedded into the `R1` route.

Comment: @Peter: I have added few constraints that must be satisfied while solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

Is this even a problem?

Given you have a [OnCompletion](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) in the route that counts the number of messages in the folder and if there is no files, then shutdown the route.

Comment: onCompletion is called per message. I want a hook which will be called when all messages are completed (as per the route start time snapshot)

Comment: Define "all". Message processing in a route is a continuous operation, not a discreet batch operation. It keeps grabbing files from the directory as they appear. So, since I guess you consider that an empty source folder equals "all messages are completed", you can do such a simple check every time a message has been completed and decide if that's the last one.

Comment: I agree with you...I want to shutdown route when all logs are copied. Till that its fine. How can I detect a folder to be empty...i mean, if I do it on my own logic which will not be similar with Camel's logic to trace which files are already copied. I may see a file present in A directory, so for me this is not empty and route has not yet completed. But may be, camel has already copied the file, so from its perspective its an empty folder. Is there anyway to get this information from camel?

Comment: The file component has a lot of options like preMove, move, delete etc. which renames/deletes/moves the file when processing state changes. You can figure out if camel is processing a file by correlating with preMove filename pattern. Anyway, when the folder is empty, you're done. That seem simple enough.

Comment: when folder is done, I need to stop route R ...i.e. a handle is required where from I will invoke stopRoute(). I have no write access on A, thus can not rename/delete/move any file from there. Still I want a callback method, which ensures me that all files are copied i.e. called by Camel only when all files done.